# Extract string from API request does not work

Tags: php, api, steam

So I am trying to code a .php file that should extract a string from an API call (example of text to be extracted here: https://gyazo.com/1efffc2360bd6aba15ece3437251aebd)

Code:

```
<?php
$item = $_GET['item'];
$item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
$item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
$item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
$item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);
@include_once ("pdocon.php");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name=?");
$stmt->execute(array($item));
$rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!empty($rs)) {
        if(time()-$rs["lastupdate"] < 604800) die($rs["cost"]);
}
$link = "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=(NOTSHOWINGYOUGUYSMYAPIKEY)&names=".$item;
$string = file_get_contents($link);
$json = $string;

$obj = json_decode($json);
//print $obj->{"median_price"}; // 12345
//$obj = json_decode($string);
if($obj->{'status'} == "success") die("notfound");
$lowest_price = $obj->{'price'};
$lowest_price=str_replace("$", "", $lowest_price);
$lowest_price = (float)($lowest_price);

//$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM items WHERE name=?");
//$stmt->execute(array($item));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE items SET `cost` = ?,`lastupdate` = ? WHERE `name` = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($lowest_price, time(), $item));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO items (`name`,`cost`,`lastupdate`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($item, $lowest_price, time()));
echo $lowest_price;
?>
```

The problem is that the code does not extract the string I need (the $lower_price variable). I tried running it by defining the $item variable myself in hash market name value format and also by using the displayed script. No result. Any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After deserializing the JSON, you would need to access the `price` value like:

```
$lowest_price = $obj->data->prices[0]->price;
```

That being said, you may also need to account for that fact that since `$obj->data->prices` is an array, that it may contain more than one element.  So if you truly wanted to determine the "lowest price" (as your variable is named), you would likely need to iterate over `$obj->data->prices` to find which item in the array have the lowest `price` value.

You didn't ask about this, but you also have some weird logic around your SQL update/insert (upsert).  If your intent is to either update an existing record, or insert a new one if one doesn't exist, you might consider an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` type of query.

Comment: Oh and I think $lowest_price=str_replace("$", "", $lowest_price); is written wrong too right? It searches for $ but the API result does not contain it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @bagda391  I wouldn't say it is "wrong".  It just does nothing if the API will always return price without currency symbol.

Comment: basically its useless. so I can delete it

Answer (score 1):

I suggest getting using pdo instead of mysql but that is just me